# Rendering in Vertical Layout fails to occur

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a timeline app for visualization of certain time-sensitive requirements information and have begun experimentation with Qt since I am new to it. The problem I am having is that the rendered object will show up if I render it just basically on the main background, but when I tried to add the TimeLine objects to the vertical layout I have on my UI they refuse to render.

Here is my main window code for creating the objects:

```
void MainWindow::drawTimelines()
{
    for(int i=0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        TimeLine *tl = new TimeLine(this, this);
//        ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(tl, 0, Qt::AlignLeft);

        tl->lower();
        QPoint * dest = new QPoint(this->width() - (this->width() / 12), i * this->height() / 4 + this->height() / 4);
        QPoint * src = new QPoint(this->width() / 12, i * this->height() / 4 + this->height() / 4);

//        tl->setGeometry(0, 0, this->width(), 100);
        tl->setGeometry(src->x(), src->y(), this->width(), 100);
        tl->updateGeometry();

        QPoint *startPt = new QPoint(src->x(), 50);
        QPoint *endPt = new QPoint(dest->x(), 50);
//        QPoint *src = new QPoint(this->width() /8, 50);
//        QPoint *dest = new QPoint(this->width() - (this->width() / 8), 50);

        tl->setSrcPt(startPt);
        tl->setDestPt(endPt);
        tl->setNumSegments(3);

        timeLineList.push_back(tl);
        timeLineList.at(i)->show();
    }
    update();
}
```

Here is the maint function present in the TimeLine object itself:

```
void TimeLine::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{
    QRectF frame(QPointF(sourcePoint->x(), sourcePoint->y()), geometry().size());

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::FlatCap));
    painter.drawRoundedRect(frame, 10.0, 10.0);

    int translateAmount = sourcePoint->y() - window->getPainterY();
    painter.translate(0, translateAmount);
//    window->setPainterY(translateAmount);

    painter.drawLine(sourcePoint->x(), 25, destPoint->x(), 25);

    for(int i = 0; i <= numSegments; i++){
        int xPoint = ((destPoint->x() - sourcePoint->x()) * i / numSegments) + sourcePoint->x();
        int yPoint = 25;
        painter.drawLine(xPoint, yPoint + 20, xPoint, yPoint - 20);
    }

    QWidget::paintEvent(event);
}
```

For reference, the verticalLayout is meant to have one

The TimeLines (and bounded rect boxes) do not render when I have the

```
//        ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(tl, 0, Qt::AlignLeft);
```

uncommented. As you can see from a bunch of the other commented lines, I have tried numerous other things to try and render these TimeLines. I have tried:

- changing reference points of the geometry to be (0,0) for the new segment of the vertical layout
- changing the size of the geometry
- both translating and not translating the painter
- changing line thickness, type of line, etc.
- even tried rendering something else simple in the vertical layout

The part that confuses me is that even the bounded rect made based on the geometry of the TimeLine frame gets cut off on the side and top of the timeline (it only shows top left corner and the top and left side-lines) even when rendered on the normal screen.

Comment: Layouts are definitely way to go. `TimeLine` probably doesn't show up, because it thinks it is empty. Use [minimumSize](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop), [sizeHint](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop)  for `TimeLine`. And don't use `window` or anything in `paintEvent`. It makes `TimeLine` dependent to others. Use `width()` and `height()` instead.

Comment: @Kao thank you! Setting the minimumSize saved me. It finally made it so that the verticalLayout gave it enough space!